Using workstation to host in network database with Flask and SQLite
I want to setup a simple database accessible via the web for in network users (no more than 4 or 5 ever) hosted from a workstation in the network. I decided to try SQLite and FLask to achieve this, definitely open to suggestions for other options, but have hit a road block.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template, redirect, url_for, send_from_directory
import sqlite3
import os

# Initialize Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# Database Connection Function

DATABASE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'database.db')

def get_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE)
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row 
    return conn


# Home Page Route

@app.route('/')
def index():
    conn = get_db()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM samples")
    samples = cursor.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('index.html', samples=samples)


@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_connection(exception):
    conn = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if conn is not None:
        conn.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

Using a simple index.html, not sure if really necessary to show here. My terminal is then showing:
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://XXX.XX.XX.XX:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit

However, neither my local host IP or the actual IP is showing anything, the actual IP shows err received no response, and the local is just a white screen.
I understand this may be a very simple question but I haven't found a solution online. Thanks.
